# Are most TeX fonts other than Computer Modern optimized for \frenchspacing?

Tags: fonts, spacing, frenchspacing

I assume that when Don Knuth created his Computer Modern fonts, he optimized them, at least in his opinion, for `\nonfrenchspacing`. But since almost all books that aren't created with TeX have no extra space after punctuation, are most other fonts set up for use in TeX optimized for `\frenchspacing`, with any settings for `\nonfrenchspacing` being made as an afterthought?

Comment: How can you optimize a font for nonfrenchspacing?

Comment: `\frenchspacing` refers just to the spacings *after* punctuation (actually it's a bad name, in my opinion). Fonts *can't* be optimized for the French rules; for instance, the space before and after a colon must be the same as any interword space in the line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer presumably MSC believes that the the extra spacing after punctuation is somehow coded into the font.

Comment: @wasteofspace -- since i can't believe that anyone would fail to insert a space either between words or after punctuation (yes, i've seen samples of text that deliberately did that, but they're not "real"), i second ulrike's question.  the concept of optimization for *either* mode is nonsensical.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Some non-European text have that as optional or forbidden.

Comment: You should make clear what you mean by “French spacing”.

Comment: @percusse -- if you're referring to languages such as (i believe) burmese, where text runs continuously without spaces, and breaking between glyphs depends on traditional rules, then i know of the concept.  but if you're referring to something else, can you cite some references where i can learn about it?  (in any event, that's quite different from the concept of `\frenchspacing` as implemented for tex and "western" languages.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I only meant the space after the comma and period. It is sometimes not used and when used some people mumble harsh words :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fonts designed for TeX typically encode seven values which are available to TeX via the `\fontdimen` command:  `font_slant`, `font_normal_space`, `font_normal_stretch`, `font_normal_shrink`, `font_ex_height`, `font_quad`, and `font_extra_space`.  These are in order; you get at them with `\fontdimen1`, `\fontdimen2`, and so on.

Extra space after punctuation is governed by `\fontdimen7`, defined in the Metafont source as `font_extra_space`.  In `cmr`, for example, `\fontdimen7` is set to `2u#`, which is deep Metafont magic that we don't need to get into right here.  (Not really deep, actually; but not really relevant here, either.)

These `\fontdimen` values can be manipulated by TeX, however.  For example, to get `\frenchspacing` behavior after punctuation with the Computer Modern fonts, you simply say reset `\fontdimen7` for those fonts.  So, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\font\cmr=cmr10
\cmr Hello.  I'm Joe.

\fontdimen7\cmr=0pt
Hello. I'm Joe.
\end{document}
```

Depending on the font format, TeX will get the values for the `\fontdimen` parameters from different places.  With Computer Modern and other Metafont fonts, they are set in the Metafont source and taken by TeX from the `tfm` file.

This is a long way of saying a short answer:  no, fonts are not optimized for `\frenchspacing` or otherwise; but they do set the values which will be used in both cases, unless those values are overridden by TeX.